# Is it possible/planned to enable assigining a PSTN number to a teams bot?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Now that the Calling API for teams is available (beta)  we are very interrested about assiging a PSTN phone number to a calling teams bot.
Are there any work planned around this ?

Many thanks !

Comment: What is the PSTN? Could you please provide more detail information about your question?

Comment: Thanks @kikang for your quick response !
We are currently developing a Bot for teams that answer calls form teams users.. 
What we want to achieve is that this bot have its own public DID phone number and mobile user cans join it also (not only teams tenant users). 
We know that we can assign  Phone numbers to teams user already and there are a service number concept for reception for example but we are interested about assigning one to a bot.